# How to load the value stored in extended register(eax) into st0 of floating point stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x87

How do I load the value stored in extended register(eax) into st0 of floating point stack?

```
fld dword [eax]
```

When I use the above instruction, I do not get the desired change in transfer maybe because the bracket signs have something to do with memory address and not content. 
Though, I am not sure.

Comment: Is EAX an integer or does it already contain a floating point value?

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt to load *EAX* using this instruction won't do what you think it does:

```
fld dword [eax]
```

This loads the 32-bit floating point value from the memory location pointed to by *EAX* (this is [indirect addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes)). I believe you want to load *ST(0)* with the value of *EAX* instead.

---

If you do have to use *x87 FPU* instruction rather than something like *SSE* then I'd recommend storing the value in *EAX* temporarily on the stack rather than at a fixed memory location like @quasar66 suggested. Putting it on the stack also allows your code to become [re-entrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).

If the code is in a function that already allocates space for temporaries, just increase the stack allocation to allow another 32-bit value to be stored to it and move *EAX* to that stack location and then use `fld` to load from there.

Ultimately the 32-bit code could have been written to have a *similar effect* as:

```
push EAX           ; Store EAX to top of stack
fld dword [esp]    ; Load 32-bit DWORD value at top of stack to ST(0)    
POP EAX            ; Restore stack, alternatively could have used add esp, 4         
; do other floating point work here
```

---

On 64-Bit OSes that follow the System V 64-bit ABI (doesn't apply to 64-bit Windows) you can move data directly to the stack's [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) without fear of it being clobbered. Such 64-bit code could have looked like this:

```
mov [rsp-4], eax   ; Temporarily place EAX in the stack's red zone beneath current RSP
fld dword[rsp-4]   ; Load it into ST0
; do other stuff here
                   ; No need for stack cleanup
```

Do not attempt this in 32-bit code as it is possible for an an asynchronous event (signal etc) to clobber the value on the stack after the `mov` and before the `fld`.

---

What isn't clear in your question is whether the value in *EAX* is an integer or it happens to be a 32-bit floating point value already. If it were an integer you'd have to replace [FLD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FLD.html) with [FILD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FILD.html) in my answers to convert the integer value to a floating point value when loaded onto the FPU stack.

Comment: FreeBSD's x86-64 user-space ABI uses a red zone the same as Linux's.  Is there some other BSD that doesn't, that you were talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The FLD instruction can only read from memory, so you need to save the value of EAX into a memory location and then do a memory upload.

```
a_memory_place    dd     ?
.
mov dword ptr [a_memory_place],eax
fld dword ptr [a_memory_place]      ; loads a 32 bit data into ST(0)
```

Trust this helps

Comment: `dword ptr` is _MASM_, OP tagged _NASM_ which would be `mov dword` and `fld dword` without the `ptr` token.

Comment: A static storage location is a bad choice for general-purpose usage.  Better: reserve some stack space and use `[esp]` (or `[ebp - something]` if you made a stack frame).  Or `push eax`, like Michael suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
  fld     dword ptr [eax]
```

This code works good!
But **eax** must point to valid 32 bit real!
If you are using 64 bit real then use:

```
  fld     qword ptr [eax]
```